# Awk: Characters-frequency from one text file?

Tags: awk, character, cjk, frequency-analysis, word-frequency

**Given a multilangual .txt files** such as:

```
But where is Esope the holly Bastard
But where is 생 지 옥 이 군
지 옥 이
지 옥
지
我 是 你 的 爸 爸 ！
爸 爸 ！ ！ ！
你 不 會 的 ！
```

I **counted space-separated words' word-frequency using this Awk function** :

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' RS=" |\n" myfile.txt | sort
```

Getting the elegant :

```
1 생
1 군
1 Bastard
1 Esope
1 holly
1 the
1 不
1 我
1 是
1 會
2 이
2 But
2 is
2 where
2 你
2 的
3 옥
4 지
4 爸
5 ！
```

**How to change it to count characters-frequency ?**

---

**EDIT:** For **Characters-frequency,** I used (@Sudo_O's answer):

```
$ grep -o '\S' myfile.txt | awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' | sort > myoutput.txt
```

For **word-frequency**, use:

```
$ grep -o '\w*' myfile.txt | awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' | sort > myoutput.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method:

```
$ grep -o '\S' file | awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' 
3 옥
4 h
2 u
2 i
3 B
5 ！
2 w
4 爸
1 군
4 지
1 y
2 l
1 E
1 會
2 你
1 是
2 a
1 不
2 이
2 o
1 p
2 的
1 d
1 생
3 r
6 e
4 s
1 我
4 t
```

Use redirection to save the output to a file:

```
$ grep -o '\S' file | awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' > output
```

And for sorted output:

```
$ grep -o '\S' file | awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' | sort > output
```

Comment: Thanks! Happy YOU answered!

Comment: Funny, both **$ grep -o . file** and **$ grep -o '\S' file** works. Are them both correct ?

Comment: @Hugolpz good spot. No it's not correct.. originally I posted `grep -o .` but the would match the whitespace so I change it to `grep -o '\S'` where `\S` is the regexp shorthand that matches any non-whitespace characters.