# Awk: How to work on multiple files.txt in folder and subfolders?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, cjk

**Given a folder with subfolders themselves with multilangual .txt files** such as:

```
But where is Esope the holly Bastard
But where is 생 지 옥 이 군
지 옥 이
지 옥
지
我 是 你 的 爸 爸 ！
爸 爸 ！ ！ ！
你 不 會 的 ！
```

I already know how to **[count space-separated word-frequency within ONE file.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601997/awk-characters-frequency-from-one-text-file/15602055#15602055)** :

```
$ grep -o '\w*' myfile.txt | awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' | sort > myoutput.txt
```

Getting the elegant :

```
1 생
1 군
1 Bastard
1 Esope
1 holly
1 the
1 不
1 我
1 是
1 會
2 이
2 But
2 is
2 where
2 你
2 的
3 옥
4 지
4 爸
5 ！
```

**How to change the code to work on multiples files within a folder and its subfolders, all presenting a similar pattern ( *.txt at least) ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) command for that. Like this:

```
find -iname '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; | grep -o '\w*' | awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' | sort
```

I'm using the the option `-exec` to cat every *.txt file in the current directory and it's subdirs. The output will get piped to your grep|awk|sort pipe.

Comment: Ok, it works. I wait some different proposals before validation. **Note:** *find* also look into hidden files. My working directory being an USB I was also looking in my previously-deleted files getting twice the amount expected. (Funny).

Comment: To exclude hidden files (those which name's starting with a dot '.') you can refine the find pattern. like this: `-iname '[^\.].*.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

#### Why using `find` ?

Using glob should be enough.

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' *.txt | sort > out.txt
```

or to support recursive directory structure, you'll need to enable [`globstar` option](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) and use `**` :

```
shopt -s nullglob
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' *.txt | sort > out.txt
```

#### Tweak

You'll need to look into the `awk`-way to do the equivalent of the `grep -o \w*`, something like (the `/[[:alpha:]]+/` part):

```
awk '/[[:alpha:]]+/{print $0}' *.txt
```